# when I try to translate the element through js, it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

All the elements with class em, needs to be shown once at the time on the basis of the rating.
I made the emoji contaneir as big as the icons, so with overflow hidden only one can be shown.
The problem is that when i try to modify the transform property, it doesn't work.

```js
const starsEl = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-star");
const ratingcEl = document.querySelectorAll(".em");
console.log(ratingcEl)


starsEl.forEach((starsEl, index) => {
  starsEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log('click')
    updateRating(index);
  });
});

function updateRating(index) {
  starsEl.forEach((starsEl, idx) => {
    if (idx <= index) {
      starsEl.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      starsEl.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });


  ratingcEl.forEach((ratingcEl) => {
    console.log(index)
    ratingcEl.style.transform = `translateX(- ${ 50 * index}px)`;
  });

}
```

```css
.emoji-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.emoji-container i {
  margin: 1px;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<body>
  <div class="feedback-container">
    <div class="emoji-container">
      <i class="em fa-regular fa-face-angry fa-3x"></i>
      <i class="em fa-regular fa-face-frown fa-3x"></i>
      <i class="em fa-regular fa-face-meh fa-3x"></i>
      <i class="em fa-regular fa-face-smile fa-3x"></i>
      <i class="em fa-regular fa-face-laugh fa-3x"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="rating-container">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2x "></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2x "></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2x "></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2x "></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2x "></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="emojii.js"></script>


</body>
```

I want the icons to translate left, in order to show the right face for the rating.

Answer (score 0):

This can be greatly simplified. Removed all position/transform/display rules from CSS. They bring unnecessary complexity for such a simple task. Also added gold color for stars with `active` class and started with 5 active star.

```js
const starsEl = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-star");
const emoji = document.getElementById("emoji");
const emojis = ["angry", "frown", "meh", "smile", "laugh"]; // just the changing parts

starsEl.forEach((starsEl, index) => {
  starsEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    updateRating(index);
  });
});

function updateRating(index) {
  starsEl.forEach((starsEl, idx) => {
    if (idx <= index) {
      starsEl.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      starsEl.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });

  emoji.classList = ["em fa-regular fa-face-" + emojis[index] + " fa-3x"];
}
```

```css
#rating-container > .active {
  color: gold;
}
#emoji-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<body>
  <div id="feedback-container">
    <div id="rating-container">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2x active"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2x active"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2x active"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2x active"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-2x active"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="emoji-container">
      <i id="emoji" class="em fa-regular fa-face-laugh fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="emojii.js"></script>
</body>
```